# Stored procedure hangs occasionally

Tags: performance, oracle, stored-procedures, locking

I have a stored procedure in Oracle 11g that hangs time by time. When this happens I can't recompile it either and the only option I have is to kill SQL Developer process. I agree that the procedure does scan tons of records across different tables, views and materialized views but when there's no such problem it only takes 1-2 seconds to return the result set. I've tried killing all the sessions and even restarting the database but nothing seems to help. And it just gets fixed by itself. I'm posting the procedure content in case you need to see

```
    create or replace
PROCEDURE                                     SP_STAJ_FOR_AGAPUS(
    V_SSN IN NUMBER,
    V_WEYEARNEW OUT NUMBER,
    V_WEMONTHNEW OUT NUMBER,
    V_WEDAYNEW OUT NUMBER,
    V_LS_YEAR OUT NUMBER,
    V_LS_MONTH OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(TRUNC(MDC.DAY_COUNT / 360),0) WEYEARNEW, NVL(TRUNC(MOD(MDC.DAY_COUNT,360) / 30),0)
    WEMONTHNEW, NVL(MOD(MOD( MDC.DAY_COUNT,360),30),0) WEDAYNEW,NVL(LS.LS_YEAR,0)LS_YEAR,NVL(
    LS.LS_MONTH,0)LS_MONTH
  INTO V_WEYEARNEW,V_WEMONTHNEW,V_WEDAYNEW,V_LS_YEAR,V_LS_MONTH
  FROM SSPF_CENTRE.PERSONS PER
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT SSN, SUM(DAY_COUNT) DAY_COUNT FROM
        ( SELECT SSN, YEAR, AG.CHECK_PERIOD_MDSS(SSN,YEAR) DAY_COUNT FROM
            ( SELECT SSN, YEAR FROM SSPF_CENTRE.PERSON_ACCOUNTS GROUP BY SSN,YEAR
            UNION ALL
            SELECT SSN, SPECIAL_YEAR YEAR
        FROM SSPF_CENTRE.person_accounts_06
        GROUP BY SSN,SPECIAL_YEAR            
            UNION ALL SELECT
                P.COMMON_SSN, PA.YEAR FROM SSPF_CENTRE.PERSON_ACCOUNTS PA, SSPF_CENTRE.PERSONS P
              WHERE
                --COMMON_SSN = V_SSN AND
                PA.SSN = P.SSN(+) AND P.COMMON_SSN <> P.SSN GROUP BY P.COMMON_SSN,PA.YEAR
            ) GROUP BY SSN,YEAR
        ) GROUP BY SSN
    ) MDC ON PER.SSN=MDC.SSN
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT SSN, AG.CALCULATE_YEAR(LS_DAYS) LS_YEAR, AG.CALCULATE_MONTH( LS_DAYS) LS_MONTH FROM
        ( SELECT SSN, GET_DAYS(SSN) LS_DAYS FROM MAT_SERVICE_NEW GROUP BY SSN
        )
    ) LS ON PER.SSN=LS.SSN
  WHERE PER.SSN=V_SSN;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  BEGIN
    V_WEYEARNEW:=0;
    V_WEMONTHNEW:=0;
    V_WEDAYNEW:=0;
    V_LS_YEAR:=0;
    V_LS_MONTH:=0;
  END;
END SP_STAJ_FOR_AGAPUS;
```

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can be hard to diagnose even when we're sitting at the server with access to all the tools.  Remotely is virtually impossible.

But here are a couple of observations:

1. in Oracle writers don't block readers.   So this is not a locking problem (except, see next point).  But perhaps there is something other transaction occurring simultaneously which sucks up all the system resource?  You'd need access to V$SESSION at the very least to tell that, and preferably OEM.
2. You appear to have a couple of functions in your query (AG.CALCULATE_YEAR, GET_DATES, etc).  Now they shouldn't be writing database state, but itr would be worthwhile looking at what they do do, in case they have a dependency of particular resources.

Comment: The weird thing though is if I run any SQL against any of the relations used inside the procedure I get the result in a lightening speed. There's no problem when I execute the functions independently. The content of the functions is so huge that it's not a good idea to post them here, but to give a general idea, those functions also select from the same tables, views.